# IOS app development in Swift: Creating category menu at top of feed?

Tags: ios, swift, search, filter

I am trying to make a feed for my IOS app with filtering/categorical capabilities using scopeButtonTitles. I am able to list all my categories but am not able to fully view all of them because they appear on one line, so each one is cut off.  How can I display the categories on several lines so they are clearly readable?

Currently, we have searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [ARRAY OF CATEGORIES]. 
All the categories appear on one line, and I want them to appear on 2 or 3 lines.

var categories = ["All", "Clothing", "Transportation", "Electronics",
                          "Home Goods", "Books & School Supplies", "Free", "Other"]

```
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = categories
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    definesPresentationContext = true
    self.collectionView?.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
```

[Simulator Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmGhB.png)

Comment: You will have to use some other UI to handle many categories like that, as segmented controls (and thus a search bar's scope buttons) do not support multiple rows of buttons.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for what UIs can handle multiple rows of buttons? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated?